# How to end a Fragment from within the same Fragment after it passes some data to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm making an app, and I have the following:

I have just one Activity which shows Cards in a Recycler View, and I have a Fragment that allows to edit these cards.

When the user taps on any card, the card data is sent to the Fragment, and Fragment can modify it based on user input, and then the modified data is sent back to the Activity. I want the Fragment to not display, let's say Card #1's data, if after editing Card #1, the user wants to edit Card #2, and that's why I want to end the previous fragment as soon as Card #1's data is edited, so that by the time the user taps on Card #2, there's no chance of seeing Card #1 again.

Suggest me what to do please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a fragment from within same fragment by using following code

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(ActivityFragment.this).commit();
```

**UPDATE**

*Communicate with Activity from Fragment*

**Declare an interface in Fragment**

```
public interface cardListener{
    void onClick (String value);
}
```

**Also create an instance of that interface in Fragment**

```
private cardListener listener;
```

**Make your activity implement that interface**

After implementing your interface in Activity, you get the following method in activity

```
@Override
    public void onClick (String value) {
    //deal with the data here
    }
```

Now, in your fragment, before closing the fragment,you can execute the `OnClick` method like that.

```
listener.onClick(value);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(ActivityFragment.this).commit();
```

Comment: That will remove the Frament, true. But how should I pass the data (just an object) to the Activity before the Fragment is removed?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I had been searching for a solution for hours! Many thanks!

Comment: Just another small question. How should I send the data from the Activity to the Fragment? I understood the part of how I can return the data from Fragment, but how should the original data get passed into the Fragment at the first place? It's a custom object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, so I didn't know that I could Upvote with my almost 0 Reputation points. :/

Comment: put the data in a bundle and send it with intent to fragment

Comment: Thanks for the idea!